# Files app Webdav cliente on Ubuntu 16.04, 18.04 and 20.04 does not recognize Letsencrypt Certificate

Tags: filemanager, webdav, letsencrypt

I tried to find any references for this question, but I could not find anything close to the issue.

I have a WebDAV server using a Letsencrypt certificate. When I access it through any browser (Chrome, Firefox), the certificate is valid an all goes well. It also works from the default Mac OS file browser. Windows is a no go, as it never worked from the get-go due to a "feature" on its WebDAV client, and a non-issue for us.

However, when I try to use the default Files app from Ubuntu 16.04, 18.04, and 20.04 to connect to that server through the +Other Locations option (Dave://domain.com/share), it says the certificate authority is not known.

Is this done on purpose (I mean not including the Letencrypt CA by default) Or just a mishappening somewhere?

Thanks,

Andre

Comment: Another test. When I try wget, I get the same certificate error not valid.

So it seems it is at the certificate level that it is not recognized.

wget https://XXXXXX/share
--2020-06-28 21:33:18-- https://XXXXXXXX/share
Resolving XXXXXXXX (XXXXXXXXXX)... yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy
Connecting to XXXXXX (XXXXXXX)|yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy|:443... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify XXXXXX's certificate, issued by ‘CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3,O=Let's Encrypt,C=US’:
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
To connect to XXXXX, use `--no-check-certificate'.

I replaced IP and Domain for my privacy.

Answer (score 0):

I got some help from the Ubuntu support folks.

It seems Certbot did not include everything in the updated site config file when changing the Apache configuration

IT did not send the X3 authority certificate. I just had to add the following line into my Apache site configuration file and everything started working:

**“SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/yourdomain.com/chain.pem”.**

Regards,
Andre